Can a USB-C adapter / connector improve cell phone reception?
I was searching for a USB-C cable, with an L-Shaped connector, on Amazon when I came across this USB-C adapter / connector - CableCreation Right Angle USB C Adapter, USB C Male to Female 90 Degree Adapter 40Gbps 240W Compatible with Thunderbolt 4, USB 4, Notebook, PC, Tablet, Phone and More, Right Angle.
One of the reviews for this products says:

A serendipitous discovery: When attached to a cell phone without any attachments, this 90 degree adapter somehow drastically improves the cell phones radio efficiency -- I've now gone 2 days without having to charge my phone with the same level of video viewing and browsing, where I had to charge my phone at least every day before (tested on a '21 Motorola Edge). The LTE Discovery app shows the same cell towers in use.

I am sceptical of the claim made in the review - is it possible that this adapter can somehow improve cell phone receptions too? If yes, how?
